# Handling multiple promises with different setTimeouts

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have an array with X promises and I need to return them in order of their `setTimeout`.

For example. if `P1` has timeout set for 3000ms, and `P2` resolves after 1000ms, we want to first return P2 and then P1. The code looks like this:

```js
const P1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('R1'), 3000);
});

const P2 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('R2'), 5000);
});

const P3 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('R3'), 1000);
});

async function fetchInitialData(arr) {
  return Promise.all(arr);
}

fetchInitialData([P1, P2, P3])
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('result', data);
  });
```

In this scenario we're returning promises but they're not sorted by resolve time, it would return `R1, R2, R3`.

We want to return them by their resolve time, so in this case: `R3, R1, R2`.

Comment: Are you setting the timeouts because you need to wait that long or are you setting the times to control the execution order? If it's to control the execution order, you can just have the first function call the second and the second call the third.

Comment: I tried to create a new array and push there promises with their resolve order. I've created a forEach, waited for a promise to resolve and then tried to push them one by one. But this approach was wrong as we can't wait for an array to be filled and we get an empty array.

Comment: Those timeouts are set to control the execution order. Those are random and the case is to return them in the order of their resolve time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this scenario we're returning promises but they're not sorted by resolve time, it would return `R1`, `R2`, `R3`.

Right, that's a guarantee `Promise.all` provides: The array it fulfills its promise with is the fulfillment values of the input promises, **in input order**.

You could write your own function that instead builds the array in order of fulfillment, for instance:

```
async function allInFulfillmentOrder(promises) {
    const result = [];
    await Promise.all(
        Array.from(promises, (p) => p.then((value) => result.push(value)))
    );
    return result;
}
```

There, we put the promises in the array as they're fulfilled, returning the array when they've all been fulfilled (or when any of them is rejected, which will reject the promise our function returns).

Live example:

```js
const P1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("R1"), 3000);
});

const P2 = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("R2"), 5000);
});

const P3 = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("R3"), 1000);
});

async function fetchInitialData(arr) {
    return await allInFulfillmentOrder(arr);
}

fetchInitialData([P1, P2, P3]).then((data) => {
    console.log("result", data);
});

async function allInFulfillmentOrder(promises) {
    const result = [];
    await Promise.all(
        Array.from(promises, (p) => p.then((value) => result.push(value)))
    );
    return result;
}
```

---

The `Array.from(promises, (p) => ___)` is so the function supports any iterable of promises, rather than just arrays. I did that to make it consistent with `Promise.all`, `Promise.allSettled`, etc. work.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I was looking for, great approach.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the example, it sounds like you want the `fetchInitialData` to indeed wait for all of the Promises to complete, but internally to append the result of each `Promise` to the result *as it completes*.

Instead of *returning* `Promise.all`, you can *await* `Promise.all` after appending a `.then()` to each Promise, which appends its result to an array.  For example:

```js
const P1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('R1'), 3000);
});

const P2 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('R2'), 5000);
});

const P3 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('R3'), 1000);
});

async function fetchInitialData(arr) {
  // create array
  const result = [];
  // follow each Promise by pushing to the array
  arr.forEach(p => p.then(x => result.push(x)));
  // wait for all the Promises to complete
  await Promise.all(arr);
  // return the array
  return result;
}

fetchInitialData([P1, P2, P3])
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('result', data);
  });
```